# How to display values of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I have written the following code in C to find the binary of a number using functions.

```
//C program to find the binary equivalent of a number using functions

#include <stdio.h>
void bineq(int);
void main()
{    
    int a=5,b=3;           //Initialize two numbers        
    printf("The binary equivalent of a= \n");
    bineq(a);
    printf("The binary equivalent of b= \n");
    bineq(b);

}
void bineq(int x)         // Function Definition.
   {
       int p[50];
       int i=0,t,j;
       t=x;

       while(t>=0)
       {
           p[i]=t%2;
           i++;
           if(t==0){
             break;}
           t=t/2;   
       }  

       for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
       {
            printf("%d ",p[i]);

       }

   }
```

When I run the code, I get the following values:

```
 The binary equivalent of a= -1610823072 -1610823072 -1610823072 -1610823072 

 The binary equivalent of b= 32644 32644 32644
```

When I ran the code in C Tutor(online compiler),the following error occurred at the printf statement in the bineq function:

```
ERROR: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s) (Stopped 
running after the first error. Please fix your code.)
```

The binary of 5 is correctly stored in integer array p,but I am not able to display each integer backwards.

I would like to solve the problem in the most simplest way possible. Have I missed any logic or any line in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the for loop of `bineq`, change

```
printf("%d ",p[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%d ",p[j]);
```

Also you don't need to check `if(t==0) break;` your while will do the same thing just change `while(t>=0)` to `while(t>0)`

Comment: I gave t==0 break; so that the zero also comes when I print the binary number. Thank you for the solution. I overlooked such a small mistake.

Comment: Actually, If i give bitwise operation AND like:

printf("\nOutput for BITWISE AND %d & %d: %d",a,b,1100&11001); //12 & 25

I get output 72 instead of 8